# How to wait until multiple files are processed before calling finished function js

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

The following function runs after a drag and drop operation of multiple files.

```
function getFilesInfo(ev){
    for (let i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
            let file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
            //getFileInfo adds string to DOM element
            //Note the promise usage ...
            file.arrayBuffer().then((data)=>getFileInfo(file.name,data));
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to call a function after all of the promises in this function finish.

Basically I want something like this, sequentially:

```
getFilesInfo(ev);
   //getFileInfo(<file1>);
   //getFileInfo(<file2>);
   //getFileInfo(<file3>);
   // etc.
//run only after all getFileInfo() calls have finished
processResults();
```

The tricky part is that reading the files generates a promise for each file that gets called when the file has been read into memory (part of the `arrayBuffer()` call). I can't figure out how to delay `processResults` because `getFilesInfo` finishes after all of the read calls have been triggered, not (from what I can tell), after the `getFileInfo` functions have finished.

It seems like perhaps I could somehow add all arrayBuffer calls to an array and then do some promise chaining (maybe?) but that seems awkward and I'm not even sure how I would do that.

Comment: What does `getFileInfo` do, what does it return, and why does `processResults` take no arguments?

Comment: "*I could somehow add all arrayBuffer calls to an array and then do some promise chaining*" - yes, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It's not awkward at all!

Comment: @Bergi `getFileInfo` updates a string in the DOM and `processResults` will read that global variable and do something with it. `Promise.all` seemed relevant but I wasn't sure how to implement it with the loop ...

Comment: Add all the promises created by `file.arrayBuffer().then(…)` to an array, then call `Promise.all` after the loop. And make `getFileInfo` **`return`** a value, don't use a global variable to pass the results into `processResults`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` to wait for an array of promise to finish:

```js
async function getFilesInfo(ev) {
  // create list of jobs
  const jobs = [];
  for (const item of ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      let file = item.getAsFile();
      jobs.push(file.arrayBuffer().then(data => {
        getFileInfo(file.name, data);
      }));
    }
  }
  // wait for all promise to fullfil
  await Promise.all(jobs);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way:

```js
function getFilesInfo(ev){
    return ev.dataTransfer.items.filter(item=>item.kind === 'file').map(item=>{
        let file = item.getAsFile();
        return file.arrayBuffer().then((data)=>getFileInfo(file.name,data));
    });
}

Promise.all(...getFilesInfo(ev)).then(_=>{
    processResults();
});

// or with async/await
(async ()=>{
    await Promise.all(...getFilesInfo(ev));
    processResults();
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getFilesInfo(ev) {
  await Promise.all(ev.dataTransfer.items.map(async (i) => {
    const file = i.getAsFile();
    const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
    return getFileInfo(file.name, data);
  }));
}

await getFilesInfo(ev); // will be awaited until all the promises are resolved
processResults();
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The conceptual hurdle I was running into was that I was thinking of the `then` function as returning the results, not promises. Also, many of the examples I've seen with `Promise.all` are usually just concatenating explicit calls, not building an array in a loop.

As suggested by Bergi, I simply added the calls to an array, and then passed that array into `Promise.all`

```
function getFilesInfo(ev) {
  // create list of jobs
  let jobs = [];
  for (const item of ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      let file = item.getAsFile();
      jobs.push(file.arrayBuffer().then(data => {
        getFileInfo(file.name, data);
      }));
    }
  }
  return jobs; 
}

//The call in the parent
let jobs = getFilesInfo(ev);
Promise.all(jobs).then(processResults);
```